# Run PostGIS command line functions in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-3

Is it possible to utilize the PostGIS command line functions, e.g. shp2pgsql, from within pgAdmin III?  I am using pgAdmin to connect to a remote server.

Comment: What is the purpose for using shp2pgsql in pgAdmin?

Comment: Because I'm connecting to a remote server, I thought it might be easier to use it within an interface like pgAdmin than to have to open a separate remote terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and yes. You can configure pgadmin to call external programs, like shp2pgsql-gui, out of a menu option, which can make things easier for new users (see OpenGeo Suite, for example). But a full commandline like shp2pgsql has too many parameters needed to be effectively called by pgadmin.