# Can OpenGeo Suite co-exist with Homebrew-installed PostGIS/PostgreSQL in Yosemite?

Tags: postgis, mac, boundless-suite, homebrew

I installed PostgreSQL (9.4.1) and PostGIS (2.1.7) using Homebrew in Yosemite (10.10.3). I'm just starting my way through "PostGIS In Action."  I've been starting and stopping the server in Terminal with `pg_ctl`, and interfacing with `psql`, since pgAdmin III wasn't playing nicely with the rest of my system.

I wanted to give the Boundless workshops/tutorials a whirl (as per the recommendations given in response to [How do I get started with PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/how-do-i-get-started-with-postgis/3255#3255)), but can't quite tell from the other Q&As here if OpenGeo Suite can comfortably coexist with my current PostGIS environment, and whether (as suggested in this response re [command line functions in pgAdmin](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104519/run-postgis-command-line-functions-in-pgadmin/104524#104524)) I'd lose functionality if I operate through OpenGeo rather than the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boundless OpenGeo Suite packages should work alongside homebrew as long as you either don’t run them at the same time or change the port on one of them.